# Pass search query to view

Tags: php, laravel

I wana pass search query to laravel view, for now i try use compact and compatct-> with but still results it's this same "Undefined variable: query"

I try pass hard code like single query "abc" , "bcd" etc. it's work
/kategoria?query=abc&page=2, but when i wana make some like wildcart then i cant pass variable query to view.

Search Controller function

```
public function kategorie(Request $request)
    {

        $query = $request->input('query');     


        $pages = Page::where('kategoria', 'like', "%$query%")
                      ->orWhere('tags', 'like', "%$query%")
                      ->paginate(5);




        return view('kategoria')->compact('pages')->with('query', $query);
    }
```

View pagination output (it's work but i need search results not abc)

```
{{ $pages->appends(['query' => 'abc' ])->links() }}
```

View pagination with variable and don't work :/

```
{{ $pages->appends(['query' => $query ])->links() }}
```

```
ErrorException {#745 ▼
  #message: "Undefined variable: query"
  #code: 0
  #file: "/home/mitek91/domains/test91.vot.pl/public_html/obito/storage/framework/views/653b682019bed23b6b130f5076f5c885047247fb.php"
  #line: 1
  #severity: E_NOTICE
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can append all queries GET parameters into pagination link like this :

```
{{ $users->appends($_GET)->links() }}
```

Comment: Thanks man i have this problem 13h and u help me i very grateful

Answer (score 0):

I think your return statement should be like:

```php
public function kategorie(Request $request)
{
    $query = $request->input('query');     

    $pages = Page::where('kategoria', 'like', "%$query%")
                    ->orWhere('tags', 'like', "%$query%")
                    ->paginate(5);

    return view('kategoria', compact('pages', 'query'));
}
```

This would be equivalent to:

```php
return view('kategoria', [
    'pages' => $pages,
    'query' => $query
]);
```